# Is it possible to use Google's Assistant as a base in a self made Python Personal Assistant?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, google-assistant-sdk

So, I've been wanting to make my own personal assistant using Python. I would speak to my headset, call out it's name. Give a command or ask a question. Get a response like either a webpage opening, a program, a spoken string ...

My problem is getting started. I had the idea to use Google's Assistant as a base for my project. I would like to make a framework which would make it extremely easy to add my own commands and questions. I would make something that listens for a keywords. When those keywords get triggered I can program the action that should follow. For example, I could learn it to listen to the keyword "launch", and what comes after would be queried to an array of program shortcuts I made and it would launch the correct program when I ask it to. But when I ask something that I didn't program, the call would get passed on to Google's Assistant and that would give back the response. This would save me the trouble programming all kinds of standard things like "What's the weather?", "What's the time?" etc..

Now I did some research before coming here and there's two big services that keep showing up when I try to find stuff. Wit.ai and Api.ai. Both of these are not what I am looking for. I'm looking for a base personal assistant, preferably as smart as Google's that I can use a base for my project. Can anyone point me in a direction for this? Is it even possible to find a base assistant to start working on top off like this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You came to the right tag! You're looking for the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/) and the [Assistant Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/python/). Although still in Developer Preview, it sounds like it provides much (but not all) of what you're looking for.